# Combine two Queries. If value is found in first query, skip value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been struggling with this for a few hours now, and have read everything possible online. I have tried numerous variations of this code, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Query 1 and Query 2 have matching columns and headers.  I am trying to get it so that I get the full results of Query 1. For Query 2, I only want it to show values not found in Query 1. I don't I can use UNIQUE() function as there may be multiple entries for each value in Query 1 or Query 2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(A2:F2, "SELECT *");{QUERY(I2:N2, "SELECT * WHERE not K MATCHES '"&JOIN("|",C1:C)&"'")}})
```

Both Queries work separately, just can't see to get them working together.

edit: this actually does work. The issue I am experiencing is that if all values in Query 2 match values in Query 1, I get an error. Is there a way to have it ignore the 2nd query if all values match?

Comment: A2:F2 and I2:N2 are just one row each - is that correct?

Comment: For testing purposes, yes I made them one row. In reality they will likely be approximately 1,000 rows each, and not always the same number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a trivial answer, but

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror({QUERY(A2:F2, "SELECT *");QUERY(I2:N2, "SELECT * WHERE not K MATCHES '"&JOIN("|",C2:C)&"'")},QUERY(A2:F2, "SELECT *")))
```